# How can i add a url redirect instead of a response message

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, contact-form

I have a contact form and i want to redirect me to a page instead of showing me a "thanks you for contacting us"

The message is now "Mesajul a fost trimis cu success! Va vom contacta in maxim doua zile lucratoare." i wanna remove the message and when someone hit submit button to be redirected to another page instead of displaying a message...

here is the php code

```
<?PHP

// Set header as json
header('Content-Type: application/json');

// Response
$data = array(
    'type'     => 'success',
    'message'  => 'Mesajul a fost trimis cu success! Va vom contacta in maxim doua zile lucratoare.',
    'response' => 'success'
);

// Form rules
$rules = array(
    'input-name'  => 'required|min',
    'input-email' => 'required|email',
    'input-phone' => 'required|numeric'
);

// Rules messages
$messages = array(
    'input-name'  => array(
            'required'   => 'Numele este obligatoriu',
            'min'        => 'Numele trebuie sa aiba mai mult de 3 caractere'),

    'input-email' => array(
            'required'   => 'Adresa de email este obligatorie',
            'email'      => 'Adresa de email nu este valida'),

    'input-phone' => array(
            'required'   => 'Numarul de telefon este obligatoriu',
            'numeric'    => 'Numarul de telefon nu este valid')
);


// If no data is sent
if( !$_POST )
{
    $data['type']     = 'danger';
    $data['message']  = 'S-a produs o eroare! Va rugam incercati dinou.';
    $data['response'] = 'fail';
}

// Check for spam
if( $data['type'] == 'success' && !isset($_POST['input-leaveblank']) && $_POST['input-leaveblank'] != 'foo' )
{
    $data['type']     = 'success-foo';
    $data['message']  = 'Mesajul a fost trimis.';
    $data['response'] = 'success';
}

// If there had errors
if( $data['type'] == 'danger' || $data['type'] == 'success-foo' )
{
    echo json_encode($data);

    die();
}

// Validate form
foreach( $rules as $field => $rule )
{
    foreach( explode("|", $rule) as $do_rule )
    {
        $error = false;

        // Check input
        switch ($do_rule)
        {
            case "required":
                if( !isset($_POST[$field]) || $_POST[$field] == '' )
                {
                    $error = 'required';
                }
            break;

            case "min":
                if( strlen($_POST[$field]) <= 3 )
                {
                    $error = 'min';
                }
            break;

            case "email":
                if( !filter_var($_POST[$field], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) )
                {
                    $error = 'email';
                }
            break;

            case "numeric":
                if( !is_numeric($_POST[$field]) )
                {
                    $error = 'numeric';
                }
            break;
        }

        // If error show and die
        if( $error != false )
        {
            $data['type']     = 'danger';
            $data['message']  = $messages[$field][$error];
            $data['response'] = 'fail';

            echo json_encode($data);
            die();
        }
    }
}


$attributes = $_POST;

$to      = 'office@atelierdeweb.ro';
$subject = 'Formular contact Atelier de Web';
$headers = 'From: ' . $attributes['input-email'] . "\r\n" .
           'Reply-To: ' . $attributes['input-email'] . "\r\n" .
           'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();


$message = 'Nume: ' . $attributes['input-name'] . "\r\n" .
'E-mail: ' . $attributes['input-email'] . "\r\n" .
'Telefon: ' . $attributes['input-phone'] . "\r\n" .
"\r\n" .
'Pachet potrivit: ' . $attributes['input-package'] . "\r\n" .
'Timp de lucru: ' . $attributes['input-endtime'] . "\r\n";

if( isset($attributes['input-services']) )
{
    $message .= 'Servicii complementare: ';

    foreach( $attributes['input-services'] as $service )
    {
        $message .= $service . ', ';
    }

    $message = substr($message, 0, -2) . "\r\n";
}

$message .= "\r\n\r\n" . $attributes['input-description'];


mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

// Return default data
echo json_encode($data);

?>
```

And the HTML

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-12">
            <button class="input-submit" type="submit" data-loading-text="Va rugam asteptati ..." data-complete-text="Mesajul a fost trimis" class="btn btn-default">Trimite cererea de oferta</button>
        </div>
```

Comment: What do you want to do with the data you were returning to the browser as JSON?

Comment: Thats OK, we can wait, we have nothing better to do have we guys and gals!

Comment: Sorry... This is a script implemented in a wp theme.so basically the data is send to a mail address...and after someone complete the contact form, instead of that thanks message to be redirected to a link

Comment: can someone please help me?